# Javascript color detection

Tags: jquery, colors, background

I have a car on my canvas and i have a track for the car as a background. I want to create borders for the car. For example, if the car touches a different colored pixel like black, it should give an alert.

newImage() is the image for the car that i am using and i want that to detect the new color

I tried using the code for a long time but simply does not work:

```
function collideTest(){

    var Color = context.getImageData(car - 5, car - 5,60,60);

    for (var i = 0; i < 3600; i++) {
        if (Color.data[i] == 255) {
            alert("Game Over");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the rest of my code with the car image, just in case you need this bit of info:

```
//Setting the canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Uploading car
var car = new Image();
car.src = "file:///C:/Users/Saqib/Desktop/Game/img/car-top-view-clipart-red-racing-car-top-view-fe3a%20%281%29.png";

var width = $('#gameCanvas').width();
var height = $('#gameCanvas').height();

//Setting properties of car
var x = 450;
var y = 730;
var speed = 10;
var angle = 990;
var mod = 0;

//Event listeners for keys
window.addEventListener("keydown", keypress_handler, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyup_handler, false);

//Interval for animation
var moveInterval = setInterval(function () {
    draw();
}, 30);

//Drawing the car turning and changing speed
function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    x += (speed * mod) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
    y += (speed * mod) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle);

    context.save();
    context.translate(x, y);
    context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
    context.drawImage(car, -(car.width / 2), -(car.height / 2));
    context.restore();
}

//Setting the keys
function keyup_handler(event) {
    console.log('a');
    if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40) {

        mod = 0;
    }
}

//Setting all of the keys
function keypress_handler(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        mod = 1;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        mod = -1;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        angle -= 5;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        angle += 5;
    }
}
```

A little help will be awsomely appreciated. Thanks in advance. And in case you dont understand the details i gave, please feel free to comment what ever information you would like to know, i will give a reply in minutes.

Comment: what is the data you get in Color variable ?

Comment: The car that i put in the canvas